# Self join count in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something like

```
SELECT `v1`.`date`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`v2`.`id`)) AS `visits` 
FROM `visitor_visits` AS `v1` JOIN `visitor_visits` AS `v2` 
ON (`v1`.`date` = `v2`.`date`) GROUP BY `v1`.`date`, `v2`.`date` 
ORDER BY `v1`.`date
```

To get distinct dates, and a count of all other dates that match.

I'm pretty sure this is the wrong query since the date column is non-unique.

Comment: why are there quotes around your aliased table / field names

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did you run that command? What results did you get, and what results do you need? I mean, show us some sample data..it'll help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
SELECT v1.date, COUNT(v1.id) AS visits 
FROM visitor_visits AS v1
GROUP BY v1.date
ORDER BY v1.date
```

?

ps. I assume that `id` is primary key (unique).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at distinct visitor IDs per date, it should just be

```
SELECT v1.date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(v1.id)) as Visitors
   FROM
      visitor_visits AS v1
   group by
      v1.Date
```